# Multiprocessing pandas read_excel into dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have 6 .xlsx files. With the following code, I store one of them in a dataframe, named "df_documents":

```
df_documents = pd.read_excel(path_input+name_DOCUMENTSESSENTIAL+fileending_input,
                             names=column_DOCUMENTSESSENTIAL)
```

Due to the xlsx file size, I did some research to speed it up. Multiprocessing was the way to go:

```
def read_csv(filename):
return pd.read_excel('input/' + filename)


def main():

pool = Pool(processes=8)

files = os.listdir('input/')
file_list = [filename for filename in files if filename.split('.')[1] == 'xlsx']

df_list = pool.map(read_csv, file_list)

print(df_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

How can I access the different dataframes from "return pd.read_excel"? Is there a way to give them specific names? I am aware that I have access to "df_list" - but I don't know, which file is in which dataframe df_list[number].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, should return you a list of tuples.

Where the first element in each tuple represents the filename, and the second is the dataframe. Essentially, the only difference is the return statement on the read_csv command.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def read_csv(filename):
    return (filename, pd.read_excel(os.path.join('input', filename))


def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=8)

    files = os.listdir('input')
    file_list = [filename 
                 for filename in files 
                 if filename.endswith('.xlsx')]

    df_list = pool.map(read_csv, file_list)

    print(df_list)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```